# Finding the index of values of one dataframe in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know this way for finding an index of a value in a dataframe like 1 in column a and 2 in column b:

```
index = df.index[(df['a'] == 1) & (df['b'] == 2)]
```

But if I want to find the index of the values of two columns of a dataframe in another dataframe, what is the way?

For example, for two dataframes like df1 and df2 with a and b columns I have tried this:

```
index = [i for i in df2.index if len(df1.index[(df1['a'] == df2.loc[i,'a']) & (df1['b'] == df2.loc[i,'b'])]) == 1]
```

It works and returns a list, but I want to find a faster way that its result will be like first code that i mentioned.

---

for dear gtomer:

```
df1 = 
a         b
book      1
book      2
pen       1
eraser    3
book      4

df2 = 
a         b
pen       4
book      2
pen       8
eraser    3
book      14
```

I want two find Intersection between df1 and df2

Comment: pls post sample of your dataframes and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform an inner-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
index = df1.reset_index().merge(df2)['index'].tolist()
```

Or, if you have more columns but only want to consider a/b:

```
index = df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on=['a', 'b'])['index'].tolist()
```

If you can have duplicated combinations of a/b in either DataFrame:

```
index = df1.reset_index().merge(df2)['index'].unique().tolist()
```

Output: `[1, 3]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isin`

```
index = df1[df1[['a', 'b']].isin(df2[['a', 'b']]).all(axis=1)].index
print(index.values) # or index.to_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the rows that contain the same values in df1, then convert the indices into a list.

```
index_list = df1[df2.isin(df1)].dropna().index.to_list()
```

Result:

```
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of fast instruction :

You could define whatever columns you want to make the intersection on.

```py
cols = ['a', 'b']
m = df1[cols].eq(df2[cols]).sum(axis=1).eq(len(cols))

print(df1[m].index.tolist())
```

```
[1, 3]
```